# How to ignore hash's key sequence in perl

Tags: perl, hash, key

I has a file that contain information like below

```
1:2=14
3:4=15
2:1=16
4:3=17
```

I would like to create a hash that treat key `{1:2}` same with key `{2:1}`

```
$hash{1:2} = $hash{2:1}
```

so when i print all element in `$hash{1:2}` or `$hash{2:1}` it give me both `14` and `16` as the result. Is it a simple way to do that?

Below are my planning to create the key for hash

```
for ( my $i = 0; $i <=$#file ; $i++) {
    my $line = $file[$i];
    my @key = split ("=",$line);
    my $hash{$key[0]} = $key[1];
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the keys? You could do with adding more code to help explain what it is you're doing

Comment: guess you could use `s/(\d+):(\d+)/$2:$1/` to reverse your key

Comment: @ChrisTurner i add the way i getting the keys, thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Flying_whale how to use this to reverse? Can give me example?

Comment: this is the substitution mentionned by simbabque in the case the the keys are 2 digits or more (though it will work for 1 digit).  You should look for regular expressions (known as "regex"), my comment will then be clearer to you ;)

Comment: Your `for` loop looks strange. What is `@file`? Where did that come from? Are you slurping the whole file into memory first? That means you're making another (larger) copy with your hash. If your file is very big that might not be a good idea.

Comment: yep, you should use `open(my $file, "<", "file.txt");` and a `while(<$file>)` loop instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that. If your keys follow the same pattern, you can wrap it in a function, then compute all keys that fit your algorithm and get the values.

```
my %hash = (
    '1:2' => 14,
    '3:4' => 15,
    '2:1' => 16,
    '4:3' => 17,
);

sub get_elements {
    my ($key) = @_;

    return $hash{$key}, $hash{reverse $key}; # or $key =~ s/(\d+):(\d+)/$2:$1/r
}

print join ' ', get_elements('1:2');
```

This uses string [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html), and obviously only works if the parts of the key are only one digit. If you can have numbers greater than 9 you will have to split the string and re-assemble it, or use a substitution to switch them around. My example uses the `/r` modifier, which needs [Perl 5.14 or higher](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Non-destructive-substitution).

---

If you want to however build a data structure when reading your file that takes care of this automatically, you can do that too. Use an array reference instead of the simple values inside your hash, and assign *the same reference* to all keys that you want to be equal.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($key, $value) = split /=/, $line;
    my ($left, $right) = split /:/, $key;

    # $hash{$key} //= ( $hash{"$right:$left"} // [] ); # needs 5.10
    $hash{$key} = ( $hash{"$right:$left"} || [] )
        unless exists $hash{$key};

    push @{ $hash{$key} }, $value;
}

say "@{ $hash{'1:2'} }";
say "@{ $hash{'2:1'} }";

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
1:2=14
3:4=15
2:1=16
4:3=17
```

The output of this code is

```
14 16
14 16
```

The Data::Dumper structure looks like this, which explains that both keys `2:1` and `1:2` point to the same array reference. That means that if you `push` another value into one of them, it will end up in the other as well, because they are actually the same thing.

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4:3' => [
                     '15',
                     '17'
                   ],
          '3:4' => $VAR1->{'4:3'},
          '2:1' => [
                     '14',
                     '16'
                   ],
          '1:2' => $VAR1->{'2:1'}
        };
```

The only downside of this is that you cannot get the order of the elements back. This data structure looses the knowledge that `1:2` had the value `14` and `2:1` had `16` initially. If you want `2:1` to output `16 14` this will not work.

Comment: Hi @simbabque, thanks for the answer, i getting error in this line do you know why?  `$hash{$key} //= ( $hash{"$right:$left"} // [] );` error message `syntax error near "] )"`

Comment: Which Perl version are you running @Tim? Possibly it's too old for the `//=` syntax. You need at least [5.10](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Defined-or-operator)

Comment: ya my version is too old which is 5.8.8, but  not sure i got administration to update the version in the server. Any other command i can use?

Comment: @Tim you can work around that operator. It's just a shorter version. You can always use several lines to do the same thing. I'll update.

Comment: @ simbabque  ok noted. Thanks

Comment: @Tim see my edit. It's pretty ugly, but it essentially does something similar. Make sure you understand what this does before using it.

Comment: You might manage something using `tie`. I'm unsure exactly if that's a horrible idea.